# IIS redirect rule not working on specific folder

Tags: redirect, iis, iis-10

I have the following file paths:

C:\projects\myproject\mysite\Content\Products\123\a.jpg

and

C:\projects\myproject\mysite\Content\img\banner\webp\b.webp

C:\projects\myproject\mysite is hosted on IIS and in my web.config I have a working rewrite rules like those:

```
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="REDIRECT_WEBP_PRODUCTS" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/webp/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="http://localhost/mysite/content/img/logo.svg" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="REDIRECT_IMAGE_PRODUCTS" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/products/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="http://localhost/mysite/content/img/logo.svg" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

So my images under Content\Products\123\ are redirected to logo.svg as expected but REDIRECT_WEBP_PRODUCTS doesn't work.

**.webp files extension is handled correctly** (mime type support is ok), so the problem isn't related to the file extension. (tried with a .jpg under webp/ folder too).

It seems like redirection is working only for request for files under Content\Products...

---

Long story short:

```
<img class="article__image" data-src="/mysite/content/products/123/a.jpg" alt="a" src="/lordgun/content/products/123/a.jpg">
```

works
but

```
<img class="banner__img" src="/mysite/content/img/banner/webp/b.webp" alt="b">
```

not.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this by putting a web.config with a specific rewrite rule directly in webp/ folder.